# Remove user from Global Address List

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I'm using Windows Server 2003 and Exchange 2007.  I created a user in both Active Directory and Exchange.  However, we didn't need the user so I disconnected his mailbox in Exchange.  When I tried to look at the Active Directory, I don't see the user anywhere.  Unfortunately, his name appears in the Global Address List.  How do I remove his name from GAL?

Some of the info I looked up mentioned changing his account in A/D.  But I can't find it in A/D to change it.  I just want it gone from GAL so that people don't get confused when sending emails.

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Sincerely,
   Charles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When did you do this?  The GAL usually builds on a nightly basis, so you might not see the change until tomorrow unless you go to "Send and Receive" in outlook, and find the Download Address Book option under there somewhere.

Or if you didn't disconnect the box correctly somehow, under the "Exchange Advanced" tab in ADUC you should have a checkbox for "Hide this user from the Global Address Book"

Answer (score 3):

Other's have hinted at this, but under EMC (not ADUC) you can go to the properties of the mailbox to remove it from the GAL correctly ("Hide from Exchange address lists"), but also to check which OU the user is in:

[image]

You can also force the Outlook clients to update the address book with the Send/Recieve -> Download Address Book option.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have Exchange 2007 but would assume the settings are essentially the same as 2003. In the user's Exchange Advanced settings in ADUC tick the box that's labeled "Hide from Exchange address lists".

Answer (score 1):

Did you verify the GAL entry via OWA? If you are checking with an Outlook client, then you might also re-download the Address book first, just in case it is keeping an outdated Address book.